# Physical meaning of this integral in $k$-space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, momentum, integration, crystals

I am trying to solve an integral in $k$-space where I want to calculate the ratio of the average energy of an arbitrary electronic band ($E(k)=k^n)$ to the square of average group velocity of electrons($v_g 
 = k^{n-1})$ approximately in the form of this expression given by $$L=\frac{\frac{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}k^{n}}{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}1}}{\left(\frac{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}k^{n-1}}{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}1}\right)^2}\;.$$  Now, I want to do this for $d$-dimensions, so I convert this sum to integral.

$$L=\frac{\dfrac{\int_{0}^{k_f}k^{n} d^d k}{\int_{0}^{k_f}1d^d k}}{\left(\dfrac{\int_{0}^{k_f}k^{n-1}d^d k}{\int_{0}^{k_f}1d^d k}\right)^2}$$ where $d^dk  = \dfrac{d \pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}+1)}k^{d-1}dk$ is the volume element in $d$-dimensional space.

I want to get a simple expression for $L$ and how it depends with $k_f,n$ and $d$. any physical insight into this integral could also be helpful.

Comment: After your latest edit making the integrals finite, they are all trivial. You know how to integrate a power.

Comment: I want to get a physical/geometric explanation for this integral in d-dimensions.