# Physical meaning of this integral in $k-$space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, momentum, integration, crystals

I am trying to solve an integral in $k$-space where I want to calculate the ratio of the average energy of an arbitrary electronic band ($E(k)=k^n)$ to the square of average group velocity of electrons($v_g 
 = k^{n-1})$ approximately in the form of this expression given by $$L=\frac{\frac{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}k^{n}f(k)}{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}f(k)}}{\left(\frac{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}k^{n-1}f(k)}{\sum_{\mathbf{k}}f(k)}\right)^2}\;.$$

Where $f(k)$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution given by $f(k) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{k^n}{k_B T}}}$ and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature.

Now, I want to do this for $d$-dimensions, so I convert $L$ sum to integral and it results in the expression

$$
L = \frac{\dfrac{\int_{0}^{\infty}k^{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{k^n}{T}}}\right) \mathrm d^d k}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{k^n}{T}}}\right) \mathrm d^d k}}{\left(\dfrac{\int_{0}^{\infty}k^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{k^n}{T}}}\right)\mathrm d^d k}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{k^n}{T}}}\right) \mathrm d^d k}\right)^2}
$$
where $ \mathrm d^dk  = \dfrac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}+1)}k^{d-1} \mathrm dk $ is the volume element in $ d $-dimensional space.

I want to get a simple expression for $ L $ and how it depends on $ T, n $ and $ d $. Any physical/geometrical insight into this integral could also be helpful. What can I do in Mathematica to understand these terms? I specially want to understand what happens at very low and very high $T$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical meaning of this integral in $k$-space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535441/)

Comment: This question was also posted by me and it doesn’t take into account the Fermi Dirac statistics.

Comment: Cross-posted at [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216034/physical-explanation-of-expanding-this-exponential-sum).

Comment: Hi Indeterminate. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.